# Mobilize.js - avoid loading unnecessary files

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobilize.js

I am using the [Mobilize.js framework](http://mobilizejs.com/) and have mobilized my website. Everything is working fine and the website looks as expected, both on desktop as well as mobile.

My desktop version of the website contains a little *heavy* background image. But I haven't included the background or any other image in the mobilized version, so that it loads as fast as possible even on the low bandwidth mobiles.

But the **problem** that I am facing is that when the website is opened in a mobile, it still loads that *heavy* background image even though it is not needed in the mobilized version. According to the [**official documentation**](http://cdn.mobilizejs.com/docs/trunk/manual/introduction.html#how-it-works), it should stop loading the images and other files as soon as the mobile browser is detected.

Here is the structure of page's `<head>`

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    //to define the structure of the mobile version
    function mobilizeCustomInit()
    {
        ...
    }
</script>   

<!-- load the core mobilize js file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mobilize/js/mobilize.core.min.js"></script> 

<!-- set the cdn options -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    mobilize.cdnOptions.baseURL = "http://mywebsite.com/mobilize";
</script>

<!-- css stylesheet - CSS FOR DESKTOP ONLY -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

As evident from the above `<head>` structure that I have included the desktop stylesheet (where the desktop-only background image style is defined) after the mobilize.js file. So the mobilize.js file will load and execute first and should stop the "main.css" file (or atleast the images that are used in this css file) to load, but it is not happening.

So what should I do to stop the desktop version of css file from loading when the website is being opened in the mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Reference this sample html page - https://github.com/mobilizejs/mobilize.js/blob/master/integrations/example/sample.html

You should be calling

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Called when mobilize.js is autoloading and init() is called
        function mobilizeCustomInit() {

             // Add new Javascript and CSS files to mobile
             // file loading list

             // Note: Slashdot at the beginning of the filename
             // indicates that the file path is relative to the HTML file location.
             // This is an internal trick of mobilize.js.
             mobilize.cdnOptions.javascriptBundles.push("./mobilize.yoursite.js");
             mobilize.cdnOptions.cssBundles.push("./mobile-style.css");                 
        }            
    </script>
```

So that you have specific mobile js and css to load.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as I have mentioned in the question that mobilizeCustomInit() is already declared and I am calling all the required things in this function. Moreover, even if I don't specify mobile specific css and js, it should load the mobile page without that css and js, but is shouldn't load the desktop specific content.

So, my main concern is how to avoid the desktop specific content rather than how to load mobile specific content.